# Spring Boot App. Вызов хранимых процедур. Модель данных

Tags: json, spring-boot, микросервисы, dto, stored-procedures

Есть классический микросервис на `Spring Boot`.
Общение с БД в основном построено на вызове хранимых функций, возвращающих json.
На данном этапе, json, возвращенный базой, во многих операциях **идентичен** json-ну, который нужно отдать, к примеру, на фронтенд.

Вопрос касательно модели данных:

- **нужен ли отдельный слой модели данных** между БД и бэкендом (по типу слоя Entity) и тогда придется **делать маппинг** между этим слоем и DTO (во многих случаях **один к одному**)?
- Или json, возвращенный хранимой функцией, **сразу маппить в DTO**?

Comment: по правильному вы должны маппить из базы в Entity, а из контроллера отдавать DTO, даже если они совпадают 1 в 1.

Comment: как таковых Entity и нет. База отдает String (json)